# error: called object type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I'm not very experienced in C programming and I'm trying to write a program using pipes. The thing is that when I try to compile it, it gives me a strange error I can't understand, even by reading other similar questions in Stackoverflow.

The errors are the next ones:

```
ejercicio.c:91:8: error: called object type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') is not a function or function pointer
                    read(tuberiaCom[0], login, sizeof(int));
                    ~~~~^
ejercicio.c:103:8: error: called object type 'ssize_t' (aka 'long') is not a function or function pointer
                        read(tuberiaCom[0], *checkuser, 256);
```

And the affected code is this one:

```
int main(){
    int tuberiaCom[2];
    int fduser;
    int login = 0;
    char username[256];
    char answer[1024];
    char checkuser[256];
    char command[64];
    char program[16];
    char options[48];
    char *line = NULL;
    pid_t familia;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    if(pipe(tuberiaCom) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Pipe error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(familia = fork()){
        case -1:
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork error\n");
            exit(1);
            break;
        case 0:
            scanf("Please, write your username %s", username);

            write(tuberiaCom[1], &username, strlen(username));
            read(tuberiaCom[0], login, sizeof(int));    /////////Line 91

            if(login == 1){
                printf("User %s exists, you can continue", username);
            }
            else{
                printf("There is no user called %s, the program will finnish", username);
                exit(1);
            }

            break;
        default:
            read(tuberiaCom[0], *checkuser, 256);    /////////Line 103
            fduser = open("users.txt", O_RDONLY);

            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fduser)) != -1){    
                if(*line == *checkuser){
                    login = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            write(tuberiaCom[1], &login, sizeof(int));

            break;
    }
    ......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a variable named `read` which is confusing compiler with the function `read(2)` when you call `read(2)`. Rename your variable `read` to something else.

Comment: It is not confusing the compiler; it is confusing the coder.  Using a variable with the same name as a function you plan to call leads to problems — while the variable is in scope, you can't call the function by name.

Comment: Than you, it fixed it.